# Scroll function takes different values of same variables

Tags: javascript, ajax

I've an ajax file which I call on checkbox selection. In that particular ajax file, I've scroll function, too.

Issue is, variables in scroll functions have different values, surprisingly.

Have a look at my code.

```
$cat_id=0;$sub_cat=0;$sub_cat1=0;
if(isset($_POST['cat_id'])){
$cat_id=$_POST['cat_id'];
}
if(isset($_POST['sub_cat'])){
$sub_cat=$_POST['sub_cat'];
}
if(isset($_POST['sub_cat1'])){
$sub_cat1=$_POST['sub_cat1'];
}
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    var cat_id= <?php echo $cat_id; ?>;
    var sub_cat= <?php echo $sub_cat; ?>;
    var sub_cat1= <?php echo $sub_cat1; ?>;
    alert(sub_cat); //This is 12
    alert(sub_cat1); //This is 0
    $('.autoload').load("ajax_autoload.php", {'sub_cat':sub_cat,'sub_cat1':sub_cat1},
                   function() {track_load++;});
    $('.animation_image').delay(2000).fadeOut();
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= ($(document).height()-350))
            {
                if(track_load < total_groups && loading==false)
                {
                    loading = true; //prevent further ajax loading
                    $('.animation_image').show(); //show loading image
                    alert(sub_cat); //This is 12
                    alert(sub_cat1); //This is 13 (because on a previous request it was like this)
                }
            }
});
```

Please note, this happens in second request onward. On first request, values passed are 12 & 13. On second request it's 12 & 0, but on scroll function, it still gets as 12 & 13.

Any body can help?

Comment: Where is the var 'loading' declared? I think it is a scope issue.

Comment: Also try resetting 'sub_cat', 'sub_cat1' values to '0' after you display the image. It may help to solve the issue.

Comment: I've not added my entire code here, just crucial code. Loading is that's why not here. And I will try your solution